# == operator skipping conditional if statement even though condition is true

Tags: c, windows

Trying to write a program for below
so here the
input will be aaabbbccc

output will be abc

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[10]={'0'};
    char ch;
    printf("enter input characters: ");

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        ch=getchar();
        if(arr[i]=='0')//skips here even though the array element has'0' 
       //in it.
            arr[i]=ch;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(arr[i]!='0')
            printf("%c",arr[i]);
}
        return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'd just like to point out that what's stated in the title will *never* be the case. If the body of the if isn't being entered, your condition is false, unless you're using a very broken compiler. It's best then to spend your energy figuring out *why* it's false.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please note that [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an *`int`*. This is important if you need to check the result to `EOF` (which you really should).

Comment: Do not attempt to destroy a question after you have received answers!

Comment: Note that `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  Assigning to a `char` loses critical information — you may never observe EOF, or you may observe EOF prematurely when a valid character is typed;  Neither is correct behaviour.

Comment: Also, the `return 0;` near the end of the program is inside the last `for` loop — it should probably be outside the `for` loop.

Comment: `char arr[10] ={'0'};` is the same as `char arr[10] ={'0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};` Also `'0'`and `0`are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
char arr[10]={'0'};
```

you only initialize the *first* element to `'0'`, all the remaining elements are initialized to `0` (i.e. the integer value zero, not the character `'0'`). That of course means that except for when `i == 0` then the condition `arr[i] == '0'` will be *false*.

If you want all elements to be the character `'0'` then you need to explicitly initialize all elements to it.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard:

§ 6.7.8.21:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have **static storage duration**.

§ 6.7.8.10:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static
>   storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> **— if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;**
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
>   according to these rules;
>
> — if it isaunion, the first named member is initialized (recursively)
>   according to these rules.

Emphasis mine.

`char` is a numeric type in C, so if you only explicitly initialize the first array element to the character `'0'` (which, by the way, does not have the numeric value `0`), the rest are going to have the numeric value `0` and the comparison `'0'==0` will be false.